# Is there anyway to download an entire RHEL repo from windows?

Tags: rhel, mirror

I have a number of offline machines RedHat machines that I need to update, and I have an active RedHat subscription for all of them.  I am unable to get an internet connection to these machines so I would like to be able to mirror the updates repo and bring it with me on a harddrive.  For other distros I have done this with wget on a windows machine, but I dont know how to do this for RedHat.

Any ideas for how to do this on a windows machine, or should I just make a RedHat machine to use to mirror the repo?

Comment: How about: [Update RHEL Servers without Internet Connection](http://serverfault.com/questions/218472/update-rhel-servers-without-internet-connection) on Server Fault?

Comment: I dont believe the 'Easy ISO' method exists anymore.  I requested additional info from RH about it and I'll post back when they answer.

Comment: According to RH the only way to download any of the packages from a windows machine is one by one.